# YouTube Data API units per day limited to 0

Tags: youtube-data-api

I am trying to implement the YouTube Data API v3 in my Python project. However it seems that I always get a error with usage limits.
Here is the specific error I am seeing:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 236433974813 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=236433974813 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=236433974813"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured. YouTube Data API has not been used in project 236433974813 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/youtube.googleapis.com/overview?project=236433974813 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry."
 }
}
```

The console says 0 quota (I cannot post images due to low reputation, but it says this when looking at the quotas.)

I have the free trial activated.

Answer (score -1):

You need to first go to the GCP console and activate the YouTube Data API for your project. You must do this for each API in each project.

https://console.cloud.google.com

Comment: Hey, I believe the API is enabled in the console last time I checked.